# what does this mean “Without hard work, nothing grows but weeds. Gordon B. Hinkley”

Tags: government

“Without hard work, nothing grows but weeds." – Gordon B. Hinkley

Comment: What is it that you don't understand. It's not an expression I'm familiar with but its meaning is self explanatory.

Comment: By expression I really meant adage or proverb.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "Without hard work, nothing grows but a paunch"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a garden, and you don't constantly nurture it, the plants you intend to grow will die, while the weeds take over the garden.  If you want to grow the plants you intended, you need to work at your garden: watering, weeding, and maintaining.

I would need more context to be certain, but I believe that the quote you provided is intended as a metaphor.  The message is that only through hard work can one succeed.  If you sit around doing nothing all day, you will not grow as an individual.

Answer (score 1):

**All good things, need hard work/effort to prosper.**

Weeds grow without any effort but they are unwanted, however anything good needs hard work, be it flowers, a career or a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

> Without hard work nothing grows but weeds.

This quote says when we want something good then we need to fight for it as the thing which we didn't want happens. This means anything thought to be achieved can't be achieved unless we do something to get it.